# Is it safe to use the Keras' clip function with max_value set to None?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Is it safe to use [keras.backend.clip()](https://keras.io/backend/#clip) function with `max_value` set to `None`? The source code [suggests](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py#L1736) that `numpy.inf` is used in this case (i.e. no upper clipping is done), but the Keras manual says nothing about it. My code works as expected with `max_value=None`, but I wonder if there is any potential problem I can run into with this setting later on. 
Same question on `min_value=None`. I am using the TensorFlow backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only possible problem is losing the gradients of the clipped tensor if all values fall into a clipped region.

Comment: How can this happen with the infinite limits or is it a general comment on clipping a tensor? I need to clip only one side, e.g. values less than 1. To do this, I want to use k.backend.clip(x, min_value=1, max_value=???). Is it safe to pass None or np.inf in max_value?

Comment: Yes it is. Values that fall below one will not have gradients, though.